# Basic local HTTP daemon

Tags: unix, http, daemon, lightweight

I'm trying to find the most basic HTTP deamon possible.

All it needs to do is allow me to access local files through a browser using the http:// protocol.

(*I can't use file://*)

Would be great if it was something that only had functionality for serving pages on localhost. Portable/lightweight would be great too!

Maybe a single script?

Comment: Did you consider using apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[thttpd](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/) is probably as small as I can think of without going into the in-kernel http servers like khttpd.   It's not directly windows compatible, but someone came up with [a version built in Cygwin](http://www.alancf.com/thttpd_win).

Comment: This also looks like a very good option.

Answer (score 1):

`lighttpd` is fairly light, it uses around 10MiB and is available for Windows and Linux.

To have lower memory usage, I think you'll need to look at web servers for embedding.

Comment: The important thing is not so much the size, but the simplicity, and it not having unnecessary functionality. Ideally it would maybe just be a single script that I could run.

Comment: Even apache if it has to serve only html files from single directory will have around a dozen or two lines in config file. I didn't really try this with lighttpd but I'd be surprised if lighttpd would be more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I think [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/) is just what I need!